# On the stochastic definition of $e$

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I've read on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29#Stochastic_representations) that one can give a stochastic representation of $e$:

> In addition to exact analytical expressions for representation of $e$, there are stochastic techniques for estimating $e$. One such approach begins with an infinite sequence of independent random variables $X_1, X_2,\dots$, drawn from the uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$. Let $V$ be the least number $n$ such that the sum of the first $n$ samples exceeds $1$:
>   $$V = \min \left \{ n \mid X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n > 1 \right \}.$$
>   Then the expected value of $V$ is $e$: $\mathbb{E}(V) = e$.

I was wondering how to show (analytically) that $\mathbb{E}(V) = e$. I looked at the references but they seems to deal just with numerical aspects.

Comment: This was answered in another question, with $x=1$ plugged in:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8508/expected-number-of-0-1-distributed-continuous-random-variables-required-to-sum

Comment: Or look at the discussion page of the wiki article. Or its archive. There was a long thread about the correctness and appropriateness of this example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have:
$$\mathbb{E}[V]=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\mathbb{P}[V> m]\tag{1}$$
and:
$$ \mathbb{P}[V> m] = \mathbb{P}[X_1+\ldots+X_m\leq 1]\triangleq A_m.\tag{2} $$
The pdf of $S_m=X_1+\ldots+X_m$ can be computed by multiple convolution<sup>1</sup>: over the interval $[0,1]$ it is given by $\frac{t^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}$, hence $A_m=\frac{1}{m!}$ and:
$$ \mathbb{E}[V]=\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{m!}=e $$
as wanted.

<sup>1) As an alternative approach, notice that: $$\mathbb{P}[X_1+\ldots+X_m\leq 1]=\mu\left(\left\{(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\in[0,1]^m:x_1+\ldots+x_m\leq 1\right\}\right)=\frac{1}{m!}.$$</sup>

Comment: It seems that for $m=2$ and support $(0,2)$ the proposed pdf, $\frac{t^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}$, does not integrate to 1.

Comment: @ki3i: It is the pdf of $S_m$ *only on* $[0,1]$.

Comment: If you have Mathematica, just have a look at the output of PDF[UniformSumDistribution[4], x].

Comment: In (1) index $m$ should start at $1$ (not at $0$).

Comment: Again: things are wrong here. To repair it is enough to change "$\mathbb P[V\geq m]$" into "$\mathbb P[V>m]$" on the two spots where this expression occurs.

Comment: @drhab: thanks, now fixed.

Comment: @drhab: by the way, it would have been kind to just fix my answer instead of downvoting it, then noticing me. Just my two cents, obviously.

Comment: Firstly I told about the index (no downvoting yet). It seemed not to help, so I put more pressure (with the intention of withdrawing my downvote immedeately after repairing). I am a bit shy/reticent when it comes to fixing myself. From now I know what you prefer in this and I will fix immedeately.

Comment: @drhab: perfectly fine. Sorry for bothering you.